# Unable to open the app from universal link through gmail app or mail app.It is working from safari app only

Tags: ios, xcode, deep-linking, branch.io

i need assistance to resolve an issue . I have successfully integrated branch.io with my ios app. My web server side send link of account verification which is deep linked in the app using domain. They send the link using sendgrid module , I have also integrated sendgrid settings for branch.io like tracking domain etc. In my app capabilities associated domains are also added with tracking domain as well.Following is the problem when i try to open the link from gmail app on iphone or opening the link from mail app iphone.
**Working Scenarios:**

1. when i got signedin from safari through my gmail account and click
   on the deep linked link , it successfully open up the app.
2. when i create a link from dashboard and open the link from that app
   , it open the app successfully.

**Error Scenario:**

1:when the same link is opened through gmail app or mail app from iphone it does not open the app and it prompts me to open the link in store, and it gives the following result, which is added in the screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have our Deep Linked Email feature integrated with your ESP because normal Branch links will not open the app from Gmail/Mail apps.

If you have Deep Linked Emails enabled, this means that something went wrong during the setup process. Please follow our docs here to ensure that you did not miss any steps:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/emails/sendgrid/

For more help, please write in to integrations@branch.io as we would need access to your dashboard to see your Deep Linked Email configuration. Thanks!